# date_diff() function not working in wordpress project

Tags: php, wordpress, date, datediff, date-difference

I tried both these methods but when i use date_diff() function it also hides other outputs too.

```
<?php $dateto=$values['date-to'];  
     $datefrom=$values['date-from'];
    //Method 1 
   $days=date_diff($dateto,$datefrom);
    $days->format("%R%a days");'
     echo $days;'
//Method 2
    $interval = $datefrom->diff($dateto);
      $days   = $interval->d;  ?>
```

Comment: There seems to be an issue with your code: shouldn't `$days->format("%R%a days");' echo $days;'` be like this instead?: `$days->format("%R%a days"); echo $days;`

Comment: Also, `$days` here is an object so you can't just _echo_ it. It's not a string. You can simply do: `echo $days->format("%R%a days");`

Answer (score 1):

Your function need to modify a bit as following..

```
$dateto = new DateTime( $values['date-to'] );  
$datefrom = new DateTime( $values['date-from'] );

//will give you days
$datefrom->diff( $dateto )->days; 
$datefrom->diff( $dateto)->minutes;
```

also there is another function in wordpress to make time difference

```
$from= strtotime( $dateform );
$to = strtotime( $dateto );
human_time_diff( $from, $to );
```

it will automatically give you hours, mins and seconds

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
This will give you the difference of 2 dates as days

```
 $datef = strtotime($datefrom);
  $datet = strtotime($dateto);
  $diff = $datet - $datef;
  $days =round($diff / 86400);
```